# Show json with AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs

Im new to AngularJS. Now I have a json object from my spring controller, how do i use/print in my jsp?

I tried something like this. the console shows the json perfectely, and with angular it does not...

```
<div data-ng-init="stats=${stats}">
    <li data-ng-repeat="stat in stats">{{stat.name}}</li>
</div>

<script>
    console.log(${stats});
</script>
```

Json:

```
{ "Types": [{"name": "study", "value":0},{"name": "health", "value":0},{"name": "culture", "value":0},{"name": "nightlife", "value":0},{"name": "other", "value":0},{"name": "friendship", "value":0}] })
```

Comment: show your json as well.

Comment: I have put my json in my question

Comment: It should probably be: `data-ng-repeat="stat in stats.Types"`.

Comment: You should use `data-ng-repeat="stat in stats.Types"`

Comment: Still not working, i got this error:
http://i.imgur.com/E17rFaI.png

Comment: What's displayed there isn't valid JSON, or even JavaScript which is causing angular to choke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because JSON string must be properly quoted if placed into HTML attribure value, you either escape `"` characters in JSON or probably better use `'` quotes for `ngInit`:

```
<div data-ng-init='stats=${stats}'>
    <li data-ng-repeat="stat in stats.Types">{{stat.name}}</li>
</div>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/XLIE9VCSn9gL3oO6ULol?p=info

Answer (score 2):

You need to reference the **array** property of `stats`.

```
<li data-ng-repeat="stat in stats.Types">{{stat.name}}</li>
```

Comment: Was it `<div data-ng-init="stats=${stats}">` generating error ?

Comment: @Vineet I think dfsq answer addresses that problem.